# Unable to pass formGroup as input to the component

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms, angular-components

I am in a process of designing a form which has some repeated complex logic. I am using reactive forms approach for the same. Since the logic is repeatative, i thought of creating a component for the same. 
below is the call from parent form.

```
<ms-diag [parentForm] = "SOForm"></ms-diag>
```

I am passing the parent form as an input to the child component. But I am receiving `undefined` as output in child component

```
  @Input() parentForm : FormGroup;  

  constructor() {
   this.text = 'Hello World';
   console.log('New Value >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>');
   console.log(this.parentForm);
  }
```

am i missing something here?

Comment: you can use a setter in the Input,e.g. _parentForm:any;@Input set parentForm(value){this._parentForm=value;..here you has value..} //remember referer in your .html to the variable _parentForm, not parentForm

Answer (score 2):

`@Input` properties are not available in the `constructor`. They are available in the `ngOnChanges`. So move your `constructor` code to `ngOnChanges` and it should work. Something like this:

```
@Input() parentForm: FormGroup;

constructor() {...}

ngOnChanges() {
  this.text = 'Hello World';
  console.log('New Value >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>');
  console.log(this.parentForm);
}
```

**PS:** This in no way imply that you should initialize your Component properties inside `ngOnChanges`. You should do it inside the `ngOnInit` method.

Comment: I downvoted, because this answer implies that `ngOnChanges` is where the OP should move his initialization code. Which is risky advice and doesn't explain that it will be executed multiple times or why. There are also other hooks where he could initialize his logic. So this is misleading. Please update the answer and I'll correct my vote.

Comment: @cgTag, thanks a lot for the downvote and the also for the reason. Really appreciate it. I've updated the answer with a comment. Hope that addresses your concern. :)